# Reduce return type repetition of functions

Tags: clean-code, dry, c++14

As an exercise, I recently implemented a simple settings reader `class` which reads setting values from an [INI file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) into an `std::map<std::string, std::string>`. The reader method looks like the following:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> readSettings() {
    std::map<std::string, std::string> settings;

    for(std::string rawSetting; std::getline(settingsFile, rawSetting); )
        settings.insert(parseRawSettingIntoPair(rawSetting));

    return settings;
}
```

I feel a bit redundant specifying the type of renturn value twice:

- firstly in the method declaration,
- secondly when declaring the local variable, `settings`.

I know that in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) the compiler can deduce the return type if I use the [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) specifier in the declaration of `readSettings()`, but this feature will force me to keep its definition in the header file too. Is there any better approach to reduce such repetitions?

Comment: I don't know how/if you do this in C++, but writing this in a functional style would remove the redundancy and also prevent potential bugs where you modify the collection of settings. I can give an example but it wouldn't be in c++!

Comment: Many approaches, not necessarily better. In your case it might be better having the map in a instance member instead of returning it. It makes sense and reduces the number of type specifications in your method to 0. BTW there is no redundancy in your code, both type specifications convey different bits of information that are necessary in different contexts.

Comment: @Goyo, thank you for your suggestions. The responsibility of my `SettingsReader` class is to read settings from file into a container, but eventually it could be the container itself which hides how become filled from file.

Comment: I'm new in this community, so I'm curious about the reasons of downvote to learn what did I wrong.

Comment: @Akira I do not understand your comment. With the approach I suggested you will be reading the settings from a file into a container and the container itself won't tell anybody how it became filled.

Comment: @Goyo, maybe I misunderstood your suggestion because I thought you suggest hiding the container too as an instance member and only provide a getter for a setting value.

Comment: @Akira You might hide the instance member or not at your will, I did not suggest anything about it and I do not think it is related to your question. But then maybe I misunderstood the question because I fail to see how the solution using a coroutine is any better than the original one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some options:

- An alias like `using Settings = std::map<std::string, std::string>` cuts down on typing that all out, but is still repeated

> ```
> Settings readSettings() {
>     Settings settings;
>
>     for(std::string rawSetting; std::getline(settingsFile, rawSetting); )
>         settings.insert(parseRawSettingIntoPair(rawSetting));
>
>     return settings;
> }
> ```

- Direct construct the return value from a [coroutine](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/coroutine/doc/html/coroutine/coroutine/asymmetric.html) - still quite wordy

> ```
> std::map<std::string, std::string> readSettings() {
>     using coro_t = boost::asymmetric_coroutine<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>;
>     coro_t::pull_type source([&](coro_t::push_type& sink) { 
>         for(std::string rawSetting; std::getline(settingsFile, rawSetting); )
>             sink(parseRawSettingIntoPair(rawSetting));
>     });
>     return { begin(source), end(source) };
> }
> ```

- Both of those ( because why not :P )

Comment: Thank your for your answer! I tested your second approach and it works very well. Regardless of your first approach is almost the same as @Ike's approach, combining it with your second approach makes it possible to change the container type from `std::map` to any other standard container type (including sequential containers) through one line (or through a template parameter) which is a very handy outcome.

Comment: Yes, `typedef` and `using` (in this manner) have the same meaning.

Answer (score 3):

You can just utilize typedefs.

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> Settings;

Settings readSettings() {
    Settings settings;
    for(std::string rawSetting; std::getline(settingsFile, rawSetting); )
        settings.insert(parseRawSettingIntoPair(rawSetting));
    return settings;
}
```

... not exactly groundbreaking material, but does the job. As for redundancy, it's all syntax as I see it -- not like anything which is prone to bugs at runtime.

Trying to make code as easy to read and write as possible should not precede making sure it's reliable and well-tested so that you don't have to bother with constantly changing it and re-reading it if you ask me, but the simple `typedef` example above is a quick and simple solution to ease the effort without spending much time thinking about it or requiring the compiler to deduce the return type from the implementation with `auto` (which would require the implementation to be visible to callers as you pointed out).

Finally it makes it easy to change `Settings` to a different type that has the same interface requirements if you ever need it -- only requires changing one line of code.

Comment: Are you sure that `Settings readSettings() { Settings settings; ...` constitutes a *reduction* of repetition?

Comment: Definitely not repetition of logic! It's why I made the little commentary that DRY applied at a syntactical level (purely for readability/writability) is something that probably isn't worth exhausting so much as making sure things test correctly and function properly. That said, a type alias using `typedef` or `using` can serve as a practical shorthand that doesn't require much thought and has benefits that make the code easier to change later.

Comment: @Ike, thank you for your well-detailed answer.

Comment: It will make changing between `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` easier. Meanwhile, it will not make changing to `std::vector<std::pair<...>>` any easier, because a `vector` requires a `push_back` or `emplace_back`. I would say that this question highlights the idiosyncraticity of the design of STL.

Comment: IMO it's actually reasonable enough that associative containers have a very different interface from sequences (`insert` vs. `push_back`, e.g.), since I think it's quite improbable that one would, in hindsight, want to replace an associative container with a sequence so much as an associative container with another. If we want to do the former, then it generally entails changes to high-level logic in ways  we probably can't hope to practically achieve by just swapping out a type alias.

Comment: ... my bigger qualm is the incompatibility of sequence interfaces, like between `deque` offering `push_front` and `vector` not providing it. There is a solid rationale there for the library designers to omit it since `push_fronts` to a vector would be an expensive linear-time operation, but I still see it as quite limiting if we want to experiment with different data structures, if only to see what types don't work so well for a given problem. IMHO even `std::list` should provide an indexable `operator[]` which could be seriously abused to produce the slowest code imaginable...

Comment: ... with linear-time complexity just to access one list element, but could still be useful to experiment with swapping out data structures. I would actually prefer that even though it could be misused to create really slow code -- to make all sequences provide identical interfaces to simplify polymorphism.

Comment: @Ike, I understand your reasoning and yes, using associative containers for key-value pairs is a rational decision. I accepted Caleth's answer because it really eliminate the repetition of type specifiaction. Anyway your answer is noteworthy too because it points out whether the effort is really worth it.

Comment: @Akira Oh cheers! Sorry, I was responding to rwong about the design of the STL and got a bit ranty there. I often find the STL to be very nice but never cared for the fact that they deliberately make even the interfaces or two sequences different and omitted certain methods solely for the sake of shielding programmers from calling inefficient methods over polymorphism,

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, here is an approach that **does not** return the result as an STL collection. Instead, it passes data into a callback. This may or may not satisfy your project's requirement; it is mentioned here just for completeness.

Two caveats.

Firstly, the signature for the `std::function` is uglier than the `std::map`, with nested angled brackets (template), parentheses (the arguments to the function), and a `void` for no benefit.

Secondly, if the person who provides the callback does something stupid inside the callback (such as trying to modify the collection or manipulate the same class), undefined behavior can be triggered. In other words, this callback approach is fragile unless all users of the code are well-informed.

Once again, this is provided for completeness' sake, not as a recommended practice.

```
void readSettings(std::function<
    void(const std::string& key, const std::string& value)> func)
{
    for(std::string rawSetting; std::getline(settingsFile, rawSetting); )
    {
        std::string key;
        std::string value;
        std::tie(key, value) = parseRawSettingIntoPair(rawSetting);
        func(key, value);
    }
}
```

The main motivation for writing this answer is if the caller (consumer of the data) is already known for **refusing to use the same STL collection type** as the function. In this case, the caller's insistence in using a different type means **glue code is needed**, so the function's author might as well turn itself into the glue code.

Such situation happens when the two side of code are maintained by different camps of developers.

Comment: Your argument is to be considered too, so your answer really completes the set of answers. Thank you for that!